# Animation triggering on property change doesn't seem to fire

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a status textblock that will display things like "Database updated" and other information for which a dialog would be overkill.  It should flash on the screen and then fade away within 2 seconds or so. The goal is that it will sit at opacity 0 until its binding is updated, then 1 opacity and fade out.  Problem is, what I came up with doesn't seem to trigger at all.  Here's my code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AppState.Feedback}" x:Name="feedbackBlock"
                 Opacity="0" FontSize="100" Foreground="Black">
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="feedbackBlock"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Not really sure where to start in debugging this, I don't get an error, it just doesn't show.

Comment: Yes, apologies, I had moved on to a different portion of the app and finally got back to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told the Binding to fire the `TargetUpdated` event. Add `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True` to the Binding expression. Besides that, you don't need to set `Storyboard.TargetName`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="feedbackBlock"
           Text="{Binding AppState.Feedback, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
           Opacity="0" FontSize="100" Foreground="Black">
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     To="1" Duration="0:0:2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```